# Retrieving an SNMP variable value (oid) using Lua?

Tags: lua

While I can see some Lua modules available for this online, (nothing via Luarocks it seems ?) all I want to do is retrieve a oid / variable value (or two) via SNMP.

I’m currently using os.execute with [SNMPGet](https://linux.die.net/man/1/snmpget).

Does anyone have, or know where I can find a standalone block of Lua code (with no require call) that can do that ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua does not know anything about SNMP. You either use os.execute to run some external software, provide that access through your host application or you use a C module that provides that data.

There is no "standalone block of Lua code" that can do what you want.

Comment: Many thanks @Piglet.   I’ll go off and explore https://github.com/hleuwer/luasnmp